# date format in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently facing this problem in my internship . also I am new beginner at Flutter. m trying to build a calendar with crud events using Firebase.
however I'm having a trouble in the date format i store the date in millisecond but when i fetch the data  m getting an ***error*** says :

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building:
type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime'
```

the conver date to second here

```
onPressed: () async {
                // save event here dady :)
                bool validated = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
                _formKey.currentState!.save();
                final data =
                    Map<String, dynamic>.from(_formKey.currentState!.value);
                         // data['date'] = 2022-08-23 06:44:36.037250
                data['date'] =
                    (data['date'] as DateTime).microsecondsSinceEpoch;
                            // data['date'] = 1661251476037250
                if (data.isNotEmpty) {
                   EventServices().create(data['title'], data['date']);
                  // EventServices().createe(data);
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
                }
              },
```

the fetche code part :

```
return Card(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(documentSnapshot['name']),
                          // subtitle: Text(documentSnapshot['date'].toString()),
                          subtitle: Text((DateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM, yyyy")
                                  .format(documentSnapshot['date']))
                              .toString()),
                          //documentSnapshot['date'].toString()
```

however the full code at :
https://github.com/desktop69/caldr.git

> caldr/lib/eventsdoc/add_even.dart
> caldr/lib/eventsdoc/home_page.dart

thank you .

Comment: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.7/dart-core/DateTime-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `data['date']` is a formatted String (ISO format). You need to parse it to a Dart `DateTime` type like so:

```dart
DateTime dt = DateTime.parse(data['date']);
```

Then you should be able to use it further throughout your program.

See also the API reference: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html

#### In your code

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  bool validated = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
  _formKey.currentState!.save();
  final data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(_formKey.currentState!.value);
  // data['date'] = 2022-08-23 06:44:36.037250
  data['date'] = DateTime.parse(data['date']).microsecondsSinceEpoch;
  // data['date'] = 1661251476037250
  if (data.isNotEmpty) {
    EventServices().create(data['title'], data['date']);
    // EventServices().createe(data);
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
  }
},
```

Comment: thank you for answering but it doesn't solve the issue either i try this code 
`  DateTime dt = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(data['date']);
                data['date'] = dt ; `
but in the terminal steal give me that error :
type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime'

Comment: i would rely appreciate if you can give me a way I'm totally stack on the flow :'(

Comment: I updated my answer. I misread your question, it seems like the DateTime is stored as a formatted string, not as an integer, so you should use `DateTime.parse` to get the correct format